# Delphi как работает ABSOLUTE

Tags: delphi

Не пойму как работает ABSOLUTE? Может , кто нибудь объяснить ?

```
R: LongWord;
RR: Single ABSOLUTE R;
```

Comment: решил переписать все функции из Delphi?:)

Comment: @Grundy, он понял, что если весь кусок выложить с просьбой перевести с Delphi на C#, то есть риск отхватить кучу минусов, а если по кусочку, то можно ещё и плюсов получить :)

Comment: статейка про [absolute](http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2010/04/absolute.html)

Comment: [ABSOLUTE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Variables#Absolute_Addresses) стоит обратить внимание на справку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
  A: MyType absolute B;
```

говорит, что переменная A имеет тот же адрес в памяти, что и переменная B

Comment: Лучше привести пример из справки со строкой и ее длиной, он, на мой взгляд, намного понятнее абстрактного

Comment: т.е. RR  будет равен R ? т.к. LongWord и Single по 4 байта, или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: @creamsun Ошибаетесь. Хотя LongWord и Single и имеют размер 4 байта, но внутреннее представление числа у них разное. Но значение одной переменной будет зависеть от другой. Совпадать они будут только при значении 0

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а если DD = Trunc(RR); ? R и RR не должны же измениться ?

Comment: @creamsun С какого перепугу? Какое отношение имеет DD к R и RR?